# Windows server 2019 kaspersky security center not visible on network

Tags: windows, port

Trying to set up Kaspersky server on win server 2019 machine. Everything went ok, until I found that server's network had a Private type. After changing it back to domain, KSC became unaccessible from every PC in network, though all ports are opened for domain network too. Local kaspersky for winserver is visible in the console, port is listened but seems to be closed somewhere:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:13000          SERVER:0               LISTENING       17092
```

There's a Mikrotik router in network. I tried to telnet 192.168.0.100 13000 on both network machine and Mikrotik terminal, both returned connection failure on this port. Other services such as rdp or smb are continue to working. Firewall log doesn't tell anything about 13000 port drops, nmap tells port is filtered. Where is the **** problem?

EDIT:
That's what I'm getting in Wireshark when trying to connect:

```
124 65.035174   192.168.0.101   192.168.0.100   TCP 66  50297 → 13000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
125 66.042763   192.168.0.101   192.168.0.100   TCP 66  [TCP Retransmission] 50297 → 13000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
```

Comment: You need to define your local and trusted networks correctly in the AV policies. The AV will not work across public networks / non-local IPs unless you define them specifically. Also, the IPs in your network should be allowed in the Firewall policy section of the AV main policies.

Comment: There's no firewall in server version of Kaspersky, so windows seems to use its default firewall with advanced security. Or am I getting you wrong?

Comment: The server policy has a Firewall policy that if active applies to all computers that have the network agent installed. Practically, the Windows FW settings will be dictated by the AV policy.

Comment: How can it be applied if all computers have network agent but none are accessible? I mean no user can't even connect to it and server can't connect to any user

Comment: If it worked before, the initial applied policy stays. One often seen configuration mistake is to block PCs in different VLANs between each other, or to use improper settings that end up blocking communications between PCs and a server like the AV server. So 1st of all, check what you have the networks defined correctly. Then, do some ping-testing between AV server, PCs and backwards.

Comment: All PCs and server are in 192.168.0.xxx subnet. Server has static 192.168.0.100 IP, clients receive their ips from mikrotik dhcp. Also if it matters, server has 2 NICs multiplexed into one

Comment: Pings are all ok from both sides. As I said, other services such as rdp or smb are working perfectly as before, just kaspersky port is being "filtered" somewhere

Comment: You can change the port in the server, but clients are already configured to listen to the original port. You should change the server port, try a heart-beat from an AV client agent and see if they can reach each-other. Also, make sure the mikrotik does not filter anything between that sub-net's IPs.

Comment: Is there any software that can tell what is actually filtering the port - the OS or router?

Comment: Try CurrPorts to see if something else interferes with the port that suppose to be used by the AV. At OS-level, you can check if you can alter the Windows Firewall settings. If you can, it means no policy is applied to the FW.

Comment: Ye I can change any firewall rule in win firewall. Also if i disable firewall completely, it has also no effect on the problem. But I'm not sure if this "advanced security" firewall can be disabled completely

Comment: Changed port to 12000, same thing - new port is filtered. CurrPorts doesn't provide any information, that's like netstat

Comment: This might be slightly obvious (and I don't know if you've checked this), but there's going to be a different domain firewall profile than the private firewall profile, so you have to make sure it applies to the domain firewall profile.

Comment: I've created rules for all three profiles for tcp/udp 13000 and that didn't work sadly.